# Alter User not working in oracle

Tags: oracle

i'm doing the follwing question

```
Managing Locked Accounts – The utility should be able to identify each locked 
account that was locked because of invalid login attempts. The utility should further 
unlock accounts that have been locked for more than a week.
```

----------------------------------------my code------------------------------------------

```
procedure Managing_Locked
is
num int;
V_SQL varchar(50);
begin

for x in (select USERNAME,LOCK_DATE,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PROFILE  from DBA_USERS where ACCOUNT_STATUS ='LOCKED(TIMED)')
loop
    dbms_output.put_line('USERNAME: '|| x.USERNAME);
    dbms_output.put_line('LOCK_DATE:  '|| x.LOCK_DATE );
    dbms_output.put_line('ACCOUNT_STATUS: '||x.ACCOUNT_STATUS);
    dbms_output.put_line('PROFILE: ' ||x.PROFILE);
    dbms_output.put_line('*********************');
     select ((sysdate - x.LOCK_DATE)) into  num from dual;
     if(num>7)
       then
         V_SQL := 'ALTER USER'|| x.USERNAME ||'ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
         dbms_output.put_line(x.USERNAME||' UNLOCK');
      Execute immediate(V_SQL);
      end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

error 00940. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER command"

i getting that error and i don't see anything wrong with the alter command

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space after `USER` and before `ACCOUNT` in V_SQL string?

Comment: oh wow thanks i didn't see that.

Comment: Write more simple `IF (sysdate - x.LOCK_DATE) > 7 THEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in order to catch each possible status the where clause should be this one:

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS IN (
   'LOCKED(TIMED)', 
   'EXPIRED & LOCKED(TIMED)',
   'EXPIRED(GRACE) & LOCKED(TIMED)')
```

or

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS LIKE '%LOCKED(TIMED)'
```

Answer (score 0):

add a space before the word account.

The user name is missing with the word "account", so the command you issue is "alter user usernameaccount unlock" ...